# How to correlate an Ordinal Categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, correlation, categorical-data

I have a DataFrame, `df`, with a non-numerical column `CatColumn`.

```
   A         B         CatColumn
0  381.1396  7.343921  Medium
1  481.3268  6.786945  Medium
2  263.3766  7.628746  High
3  177.2400  5.225647  Medium-High
```

I want to include `CatColumn` in the correlation analysis with other columns in the Dataframe. I tried `DataFrame.corr` but it does not include columns with nominal values in the correlation analysis.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am going to **strongly** disagree with the other comments.

They miss the main point of correlation: How much does variable 1 increase or decrease as variable 2 increases or decreases. So in the very first place, order of the ordinal variable must be preserved during factorization/encoding. If you alter the order of variables, correlation will change completely. If you are building a tree-based method, this is a non-issue but for a correlation analysis, special attention must be paid to preservation of order in an ordinal variable.

Let me make my argument reproducible. A and B are numeric, C is ordinal categorical in the following table, which is intentionally slightly altered from the one in the question.

```
rawText = StringIO("""
 A         B         C
0  100.1396  1.343921  Medium
1  105.3268  1.786945  Medium
2  200.3766  9.628746  High
3  150.2400  4.225647  Medium-High
""")
myData = pd.read_csv(rawText, sep = "\s+")
```

Notice: As C moves from Medium to Medium-High to High, both A and B increase monotonically. Hence we should see strong correlations between tuples (C,A) and (C,B). Let's reproduce the two proposed answers:

```
In[226]: myData.assign(C=myData.C.astype('category').cat.codes).corr()
Out[226]: 
          A         B         C
A  1.000000  0.986493 -0.438466
B  0.986493  1.000000 -0.579650
C -0.438466 -0.579650  1.000000
```

Wait... What? Negative correlations? How come? Something is definitely not right. So what is going on?

What is going on is that C is factorized according to the alphanumerical sorting of its values. [High, Medium, Medium-High] are assigned [0, 1, 2], therefore the ordering is altered: 0 < 1 < 2 implies High < Medium < Medium-High, which is not true. Hence we accidentally calculated the response of A and B as C goes from High to Medium to Medium-High. The correct answer must preserve ordering, and assign [2, 0, 1] to [High, Medium, Medium-High]. Here is how:

```
In[227]: myData['C'] = myData['C'].astype('category')
myData['C'].cat.categories = [2,0,1]
myData['C'] = myData['C'].astype('float')
myData.corr()
Out[227]: 
          A         B         C
A  1.000000  0.986493  0.998874
B  0.986493  1.000000  0.982982
C  0.998874  0.982982  1.000000
```

Much better!

Note1: If you want to treat your variable as a nominal variable, you can look at things like contingency tables, Cramer's V and the like; or group the continuous variable by the nominal categories etc. I don't think it would be right, though.

Note2: If you had another category called Low, my answer could be criticized due to the fact that I assigned equally spaced numbers to unequally spaced categories. You could make the argument that one should assign [2, 1, 1.5, 0] to [High, Medium, Medium-High, Small], which would be valid. I believe this is what people call the art part of data science.

Comment: This is not an answer about categorical column, because categories are just converted to corresponding metric values. But if it is possible - then the column is not really a categorical column.

Comment: @ei-grad There are two types of categorical variables: Ordinal and nominal. Ordinal means the categories can be ordered, like small/medium/high, which is what the question is asking, and why I ordered them in numeric format. Nominal means categories that don't have an inherent ordering, such as male/female/other, which my "Note1" hints. I don't really understand your objection. Categorical variables (ordinal ones) can **definitely** be converted to numeric values, as long as the implementer knows what he is doing.

Comment: Possibility to order doesn't mean you could replace the category by arbitary integer values, if you do so correllation would be calculated in a wrong way.

Comment: @ei-grad Thanks for falsifying your claim "if it is possible - then the column is not really a categorical column" by mentioning "Possibility to order". As for incorrect calculation, first you need to understand how software packages are doing it. When you call something like `corr(NumericVar, CategoricalVar)`, the default treatment is the conversion of `CategoricalVar` into integers. If one chooses that path, one must pay attention to my argument. If not, other "proper" ways are contingency tables and Cramer's V (mentioned in my Note1). Your comments are not adding any extra information.

Comment: Please read carefully, there is no falsifying of my previous comment. Further discussion should be moved to the chat, but I'm not sure it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to correlate a categorical column with N values is to split this column into N separate boolean columns.

Lets take the original question dataframe. Make the category columns:

```
for i in df.CatColumn.astype('category'):
    df[i] = df.CatColumn == i
```

Then it is possible to calculate the correlation between every category and other columns:

```
df.corr()
```

Output:

```
                    A         B    Medium      High  Medium-High
A            1.000000  0.490608  0.914322 -0.312309    -0.743459
B            0.490608  1.000000  0.343620  0.548589    -0.945367
Medium       0.914322  0.343620  1.000000 -0.577350    -0.577350
High        -0.312309  0.548589 -0.577350  1.000000    -0.333333
Medium-High -0.743459 -0.945367 -0.577350 -0.333333     1.000000
```

Comment: So how would you answer the question? Can you adjust your answer to actually answer the OP?

Comment: @FatihAkici I thought it is ok since it directly answers the question how to correlate categorical column in pandas, but I updated it to match the dataframe used in OP.

Comment: Please re-read the question, and also check out all of the answers given. You can not find correlation between a variable `A` and a category of another variable `Medium`. That makes zero sense. The goal is to find correlation between `A` and `CatColumn`, `A` and `B`, and `B` and `CatColumn`. Sorry to say this but your answer carries no sensible information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it produce mathematically correct correlation values, which could be easily interpreted during analysis, and it doesn't introduce any new variables, as your answer does.

Comment: Correlation exists between random variables. Not on a fixed value of them. `Medium` is a fixed value, it doesn't change, has zero variance, hence it can not have covariance or correlation with any variable. Its correlation with anything is zero. It doesn't make sense to even try to calculate its correlation with anything.

Comment: Just look the data, and you will see. It is not fixed. And it is the only (the only simple, ok, there is a whole bunch of other methods, but we are just talking about the Pearson correlation, isn't it?) correct way to measure correlation with categorical feature.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't even generate the correlation with categorical feature at all. So can you tell me what the correlation between `A` and `CatColumn` is? And what is the correlation between `B` and `CatColumn`?

Comment: No it is, you can see the correlation values for each category in the table :). Correlation couldn't be expressed with a single number for categorical feature with several categories, it would be meaningless because the categorical feature couldn't be represented by a metric value by its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no a good scientifical way to do it. I would use the following approach: 
1. Split the numeric field into n groups, where n = number of groups of the categorical field.
2. Calculate Cramer correlation between the 2 categorical fields.