# How to compute correlation ratio or Eta in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, correlation, categorical-data

According the answer to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-for-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-ordinal-numeric),

> The most classic "correlation" measure between a nominal and an interval ("numeric") variable is Eta, also called correlation ratio, and equal to the root R-square of the one-way ANOVA (with p-value = that of the ANOVA). Eta can be seen as a symmetric association measure, like correlation, because Eta of ANOVA (with the nominal as independent, numeric as dependent) is equal to Pillai's trace of multivariate regression (with the numeric as independent, set of dummy variables corresponding to the nominal as dependent).

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to compute Eta in python.

In fact, I have a dataframe with some numeric and some nominal variables.

Besides, how to plot a heatmap like plot for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correlate categorical column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894387/how-to-correlate-categorical-column-in-pandas)

Comment: @Andrew The answer to that post deals with ordinal variables vs numeric variables. My question is related to nominal vs numeric variables. Besides, I want to compute Eta, which is completely different from what is computed on that post.

Comment: ok, but eta only makes sense given a specific subset of your nominal variables. For example, in an experiment with 3 groups and a numerical outcome, eta is appropriate. The effect size has to do with the between-groups differences on the outcome variable, and would not make sense in a correlation matrix.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to compute correlation of a nominal and an interval variable? I suspect there might be a more suitable correlation for a specific purpose.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks. I want to do it as a Exploratory Data Analysis step. I have been suggested to use Eta or ICC (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363543/how-to-measure-the-correlation-between-nominal-and-numeric-variables) although I thought I should use `mann-whitney-U` and `kruskal-wallis` for nominal features respectively with two and more than two categories because my data is not normally distributed.

Comment: That makes sense. What are you exploring? Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. If I want to use` Kruskal-Wallis` and  `Mann-whitney-U`  Tests, I know how to compute them in python, but I don't know how to compute `Eta` or `ICC` in python.

Comment: @RobertDodier Really, I found [this](https://github.com/shakedzy/dython/blob/b4b22961232922622a12e8902936bd0acaeaed5b/dython/nominal.py) and [this](https://github.com/thomasgurry/data_analysis/blob/47b2e9995ea79e6782e730e801d69dda02fcaac9/python/misc/anal.py) but I don't know if they are valid or not. The first also allows to plot the heatmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is provided [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9):

```
def correlation_ratio(categories, measurements):
        fcat, _ = pd.factorize(categories)
        cat_num = np.max(fcat)+1
        y_avg_array = np.zeros(cat_num)
        n_array = np.zeros(cat_num)
        for i in range(0,cat_num):
            cat_measures = measurements[np.argwhere(fcat == i).flatten()]
            n_array[i] = len(cat_measures)
            y_avg_array[i] = np.average(cat_measures)
        y_total_avg = np.sum(np.multiply(y_avg_array,n_array))/np.sum(n_array)
        numerator = np.sum(np.multiply(n_array,np.power(np.subtract(y_avg_array,y_total_avg),2)))
        denominator = np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(measurements,y_total_avg),2))
        if numerator == 0:
            eta = 0.0
        else:
            eta = numerator/denominator
        return eta
```

Comment: Hi, I found this answer but I don't know how to apply it to a numerical VS categorical column. What are "categories" and "measurements" parameters of the function? Any example of how can it be applied to a dataframe with 1 numerical variable and 1 categorical variable? Thanks

Comment: @jartymcfly categories = categorical variable, measurements = numerical variable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer above is missing root extraction, so as a result, you will receive an eta-squared. However, in the main [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9) (used by User777) that issue has been fixed.
So, there is an article on Wikipedia about the [correlation ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio) is and how to calculate it. I've created a simpler version of the calculations and will use the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_ratio#Example) from wiki:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'subjects': ['algebra'] * 5 + ['geometry'] * 4 + ['statistics'] * 6,
        'scores': [45, 70, 29, 15, 21, 40, 20, 30, 42, 65, 95, 80, 70, 85, 73]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df.head(10))

>>> subjects    scores
  0 algebra     45
  1 algebra     70
  2 algebra     29
  3 algebra     15
  4 algebra     21
  5 geometry    40
  6 geometry    20
  7 geometry    30
  8 geometry    42
  9 statistics  65

def correlation_ratio(categories, values):
    categories = np.array(categories)
    values = np.array(values)
    
    ssw = 0
    ssb = 0
    for category in set(categories):
        subgroup = values[np.where(categories == category)[0]]
        ssw += sum((subgroup-np.mean(subgroup))**2)
        ssb += len(subgroup)*(np.mean(subgroup)-np.mean(values))**2

    return (ssb / (ssb + ssw))**.5

coef = correlation_ratio(df['subjects'], df['scores'])

print('Eta_squared: {:.4f}\nEta: {:.4f}'.format(coef**2, coef))

>>> Eta_squared: 0.7033
    Eta: 0.8386
```